# Preventing full width layouts from stretching on large screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder if there is a way to prevent full width layouts from stretching on large screens. An example for that is [mashable.com](http://mashable.com/), on my screen (13 inch) the layout is in full width. If you try to zoom out the page, you will notice that the layout is not full width.

This is how the layout appear on small-medium screens:

[image]

And the below image is for larger screen, notice that it's not full width now:

[image]

Another example, the below design is a full width layout, I want to prevent stretching it out when viewing it on wide screens.

[image]

Any thoughts on that please? How can we achieve it in Bootstrap 3

Thanks,

Comment: If you use Bootstrap it'd be a good idea to learn css as well as all examples are achieved either by modifying an existing class or rolling your own. What have you tried to do to get any of the examples you want?

Comment: I got your message in my email. If you are hiring me, then please let me know, otherwise this question can be answered on StackOverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a 'max-width' to your container/wrapper. For example:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1550px;
}
```

In this example the website would appear fully 'stretched' across the screen until the screen dimensions exceed 1550px wide.

See a scaled-down demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mumfordjw/c12txzex/)

Comment: Great idea! what if I want to make the header blue background (like Mashable) stretch on all the screen while the content inside is affected by the max-width property? Thanks

Comment: Read up on the difference between `.container` and `.container-fluid`, see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2):

By default Bootstrap uses a 1140 pixel grid, see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Simply adding a `.container` around your content makes sure that content will never grow larger.

It's possible to customize the maximum size by creating a customized version of Bootstrap using http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ or by compiling Bootstrap yourself and setting the `@container-large-desktop` variable

Comment: That won't work with my case, please check the updated question. I added another example.

Comment: If you have a fixed width simply add a container `<div>` and style it with `width: ...px;`. I think you can even add the fluid `.container-fluid` inside it if you want to use Bootstraps grid columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use max-width to stop getting 100% width on larger screens:

```
div.container{
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1024px;
height: auto;
}
```